# How to distribute assumed data across a population?

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

My database contains Properties. Some of them have been surveyed and some haven't. Based on the survey we can calculate the costs that will be incurred for a surveyed property.

Then , when a property has not been surveyed we want to assume the costs for that property will be the same as a similar property that has been surveyed.

So we go look for a matching properties in order to choose a "clone".

If the property is in a block then we look for surveyed properties in the same block, if we don't find any then we look in the same postcode area then we look in the same street etc.

If there is more than one matching property in the block we don't want to use the same property to clone all the unsurveyed properties so we rotate surveyed properties as clones.

For example, say we have 5 properties in a block and P1 and P2 have been surveyed. P3 should use P1 as a clone, P4 should use P2 as a clone and P5 should use P1 as a clone.
So the total cost for the block will be 3 * P1.GetCost() + 2 * P2.GetCost()

I have written code that identifies a clone on this basis for a single property. But I need to produce a report that will summarise the costs potentially over several thousand properties. So I think that I will need to create a view in the database to optimise this.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to work out how many times each surveyed property will be cloned across the entire population. Can anyone suggest a technique I can apply?

**EDIT**
Test sql based on the answer from anon. This gets me the count of matching properties for each unsurveyed property, but I want the count of unsurveyed properties that I need to add to each surveyed property to get the cost multiplier:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT
    *
FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.PropertyTest') AND type IN (N'U'))
DROP TABLE dbo.propertytest
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[D]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[D]
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.PropertyTest
    (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    BlockID int NULL,
    PostCode nvarchar(50) NULL,
StreetName nvarchar(50) NULL,
    IsSurveyed bit NOT NULL,
    Cost decimal(18, 0) NULL
    )
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.PropertyTest ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_PropertyTest PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    ID
    )
GO

CREATE function D(@surveyedid int, @unsurveyeyed int)
returns table as
return
(

select case when 
(SELECT u.blockid FROM propertytest u WHERE id = @unsurveyeyed) = (SELECT s.blockid FROM propertytest s where id = @surveyedid)
then 1
when 
(SELECT u.postcode FROM propertytest u WHERE id = @unsurveyeyed) = (SELECT s.postcode FROM propertytest s where id = @surveyedid)
then 2
else
null
end as Distance

)
GO

INSERT INTO propertytest (id
, blockid
, postcode
, issurveyed
, cost
, StreetName)
    SELECT
        1, 1,'G20 6DJ', 1,20, 'Doune Gardens' 
    UNION 
    SELECT 2, 1, 'G20 6DJ', 1,30 , 'Doune Gardens'
    UNION 
    SELECT 3, 1, 'G20 6DJ', 0, NULL , 'Doune Gardens'
    UNION 
    SELECT 4, 1, 'G20 6DJ', 0, NULL , 'Doune Gardens'
    UNION 
    SELECT 5, 1, 'G20 6DJ', 0, NULL , 'Doune Gardens'
    UNION 
    SELECT 6, null, 'G20 6DJ',  0, NULL, 'Doune Gardens'
    UNION 
    SELECT 7, null, 'G20 6BS',  0, NULL, 'Wilton Street'
    UNION 
    SELECT 8, 1, 'G20 6BT', 0, NULL, 'Wilton Street'

SELECT
    * INTO #s
FROM propertytest
WHERE issurveyed = 1

SELECT
    * INTO #u
FROM propertytest
WHERE issurveyed = 0

--This is close to anon's suggestion
--with the current function it returns the count of surveyed properties that match an unsurveyed property
SELECT
    #u.id,
    COUNT(*)
FROM #s
    CROSS JOIN #u
CROSS APPLY D(#S.ID,#U.ID) AS D
GROUP BY #u.id, D.Distance
HAVING D.Distance = MIN(D.Distance)

--I think this is closer to what I want
--with the current function it returns the total number 
--of unsurveyed properties that match a surveyed property
--so P1 and P2 both match 3 in the same block
--Now I need  P1 to act as proxy for for 2 of them and P2 to act as proxy for 1 of them
SELECT
    #s.id, D.Distance, COUNT(*)
FROM #s
    CROSS JOIN #u
CROSS APPLY D(#S.ID,#U.ID) AS D
GROUP BY #s.id, D.Distance
HAVING D.Distance = MIN(D.Distance)

DROP TABLE #s
DROP TABLE #u
```

This is a simplified version of my Linq-to-entities code that does matching. The GetMatch method is where I rotate the matching properties using the modulus. So in the above example we have 2 matchingProperties and 3 unallocated. If the unsurveyed property is at index 3 in unallocated, then it's clone is at index 1 in matchingProperties. But I can't see this working across an entire population so I am seeking inspiration for a different approach.

```
public class Property
{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   public int? BlockID {get; set;}
   public Block { get; set;}
   public PostCode { get; set; }
   public boolean IsSurveyed {get; set;}
   public decimal? GetCost()
   {
      //code to sum costs
   }
}

        private static Property GetMatch(Property property, 
           Func<Property, bool> matchFunction, 
           IQueryable<Property> surveyed, IQueryable<Property> unsurveyed)
        {

            var matchingProperties = surveyed.Where(matchFunction).OrderBy(p => p.ID);

            int count = matchingProperties.Count();
            Property match;
            if (count == 1)
            {
                match = matchingProperties.First();
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {
                //there is more than one property to match

                //unallocated is the number of unsurveyed properties 
               //that match the criteria and they are ordered by id 
               //to ensure consistent allocation
                var unallocated = unsurveyed.Where(matchFunction)
                                            .OrderBy(p => p.ID)
                                            .ToList();

                //we want to match the first unallocated with the first matched, 
                //second with second but we must rotate through the matches, 
                //so use modulus
                int index = unallocated.IndexOf(property) % count;
                if (index < 0)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException
                 (@"The unsurveyed properties must include 
                    the property we want to clone");

                match = matchingProperties.ElementAt(index);
                //the property to index is a
            }
            else
                match = null;

            return match;
        }

private Property GetClone(Property property, out string cloneStatus)
{
   IQueryable<Property> surveyed;
   IQueryable<Property> unsurveyed;

   surveyed = _Uow.PropertyRepository.All.Where(p => p.IsSurveyed );
   unsurveyed = _Uow.PropertyRepository.All.Where(p => !p.IsSurveyed);

   if (property.Block != null)
   {
       Property match = GetMatch(property, 
       c => c.BlockID == property.Block.ID, 
       surveyed as IQueryable<Property>, unsurveyed as IQueryable<Property>);
       if (match != null)
           cloneStatus = "Cloned from same block: " 
           + match.GetFullAddress(" ", false);

      return match;
   }

   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(property.PostCode))
   {
       Property match = GetMatch(property, 
       c => c.PostCode == property.PostCode, surveyed, unsurveyed);
       if (match != null)
           cloneStatus = "Cloned from same postcode: " 
                       + match.GetFullAddress(" ", false);

       return match;
   }
}
```

Comment: Would it be acceptable to use the average price for a property in the same block or postcode or street for each unsurveyed property rather than a different one for each unsurveyed property?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. We need to match a survey to a proxy or clone to ensure we can drill down into detail against every property, and also override the proxy manually should we wish to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is to use row numbers to match un-surveyed to surveyed properties, so for instance I would match the 1st un-surveyed row with the 1st surveyed row. I use a mod of the number of survey rows so that for instance the 4th un-surveyed row would match the 1st surveyed row if there were only 3 surveyed rows.

My query has the advantage of being able to modify it slightly to return the number of times a surveyed property has been matched.

***EDITED FOR Streets too:***

Here's the main query:

```
;with SurveyedByBlock
as
(
    select Id, BlockID, Cost, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BlockId ORDER BY ID) AS RN, 
           (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM PropertyTest P2 
              WHERE P1.BlockID = P2.BlockID AND P2.IsSurveyed = 1
             ) AS MaxNumberOfRows
    from PropertyTest P1
    where issurveyed = 1 AND BlockID IS NOT NULL
),
SurveyedByPostCode
as
(
    select Id, PostCode, Cost, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PostCode ORDER BY ID) AS RN,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM PropertyTest P2 
              WHERE P1.PostCode = P2.PostCode AND P2.IsSurveyed = 1
             ) AS MaxNumberOfRows
    from PropertyTest P1
    where issurveyed = 1 AND PostCode IS NOT NULL
),
SurveyedByStreet
AS
(
     select Id, StreetName, Cost, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StreetName ORDER BY ID) AS RN,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) 
             FROM PropertyTest P2 
             WHERE P1.StreetName = P2.StreetName AND P2.IsSurveyed = 1
            ) AS MaxNumberOfRows
from PropertyTest P1
where issurveyed = 1 AND StreetName IS NOT NULL
),
UnSurveyed
AS
(
    SELECT ID, BlockID, PostCode, Cost, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BlockId ORDER BY ID) AS BlockRN,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PostCode ORDER BY ID) AS PostCodeRN,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StreetName ORDER BY ID) AS StreetNameRN
      FROM PropertyTest
    WHERE IsSurveyed = 0
)
SELECT UnSurveyed.Id, UnSurveyed.BlockID, UnSurveyed.PostCode, UnSurveyed.StreetName,
       COALESCE(SurveyedByBlock.Cost, SurveyedByPostCode.Cost, SurveyedByStreet.Cost) AS Cost, 
       COALESCE(SurveyedByBlock.ID, SurveyedByPostCode.ID, SurveyedByStreet.Id) AS SurveyedId
FROM UnSurveyed
LEFT JOIN SurveyedByBlock
    ON SurveyedByBlock.BlockID = UnSurveyed.BlockID 
AND 
      ((UnSurveyed.BlockRN % SurveyedByBlock.MaxNumberOfRows = SurveyedByBlock.RN )
       OR -- unsurveyed row number matches left over row number
    -- e.g. if we have 3 surveyed properties that match and this is the 4th row 
          -- in the unsurveyed properties it will match with the 1st surveyed row
          -- 4 mod 3 = 1
       (UnSurveyed.BlockRN % SurveyedByBlock.MaxNumberOfRows = 0 
           AND SurveyedByBlock.RN = SurveyedByBlock.MaxNumberOfRows)
)
LEFT JOIN SurveyedByPostCode
    ON SurveyedByPostCode.PostCode = UnSurveyed.PostCode
    AND ((UnSurveyed.PostCodeRN % SurveyedByPostCode.MaxNumberOfRows = SurveyedByPostCode.RN ) 
           OR
         (UnSurveyed.PostCodeRN % SurveyedByPostCode.MaxNumberOfRows = 0 
                 AND SurveyedByPostCode.RN = SurveyedByPostCode.MaxNumberOfRows)
        )
LEFT JOIN SurveyedByStreet
ON SurveyedByStreet.StreetName = UnSurveyed.StreetName
AND ((UnSurveyed.StreetNameRN % SurveyedByStreet.MaxNumberOfRows = SurveyedByStreet.RN ) 
           OR
          (UnSurveyed.StreetNameRN % SurveyedByStreet.MaxNumberOfRows = 0 
                  AND SurveyedByStreet.RN = SurveyedByStreet.MaxNumberOfRows)
    )
```

If you wanted to get the number of times that each surveyed property is matched then change the last select statement to:

```
...
SELECT COALESCE(SurveyedByBlock.ID, SurveyedByPostCode.ID) AS SurveyedId, COUNT(*)
...
GROUP BY COALESCE(SurveyedByBlock.ID, SurveyedByPostCode.ID)
```

Comment: This looks extremely promising. I've added "StreetName" field to my test and I'm trying to extrapolate the technique for that but I think the `UnSurveyed` table expression works here with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PostCode ORDER BY PostCode, BlockId, ID)` only because a `Block` can (probably) be assumed to be in the same `PostCode`. At the next level, a `PostCode` can straddle streets....my brain is beginning to hurt...going to sleep on this :-)

Comment: You could of course add 3 row numbers to the unsurveyed cte, one for postcode, one for block and one for street. Then use a different one for each join.

Comment: Updated for street data too

Comment: Thanks Steve. I added `StreetName` myself this morning. I must have got my tests wrong yesterday because I think it was working as I expected. Then, I was exploring the join on modulus because I didn't get it at first. I think this `unsurveyed.rn % surveyedbyblock.maxnumberofrows = surveyedbyblock.rn % surveyedbyblock.maxnumberofrows` is equivalent to the `AND`, `OR` combination and another option that rotates everything by one is `unsurveyed.rn % surveyedbyblock.maxnumberofrows + 1 = surveyedbyblock.rn`. I'm sure this is the answer, I just need to look at the new numbering technique.

Answer (score 1):

Two sets: **S** (surveyed properties) and **U** (unsurveyed)

Formula *D* calculates distance from each member of **U** to **S**.  This tells you how suitable S would be to act as a proxy for U.  Shorter distance is better.

For each U, how many members of **S** are at the minimum distance?

SELECT U,COUNT(S)
FROM **S**
CROSS JOIN **U**
CROSS APPLY *D*(S,U) AS D
GROUP BY U
HAVING D = MIN(D)

```
--Example distance function
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.D(@s int, @u int)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
SELECT CASE
  WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT block_id ) = 1 THEN 1
  WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT postcode ) = 1 THEN 2
  WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT street_id) = 1 THEN 3
END AS d
FROM propertytest
WHERE id IN (@s, @u)
GO
```

Comment: This is a succinct summary of the problem and very interesting, but I can't figure out what to put into formula D. I have written sql to test this and added it to my question. Can you have a look?

Comment: If you look at the test code I ranked Block 1, PostCode 2. This gets me the number of surveyed properties in the lowest rank, but I still need to distribute them. I am pretty sure that Steve Ford has provided the answer here - just need to test a bit more. Although I do wonder if this technique is more efficient than multiple left joins with coalesce to work through the ranking.

Comment: Your attempted edit of the question was rejected (not by me) and I saw it briefly. Can you post it in your answer instead?